# Google oath all authentication with my credentials

Tags: python, google-oauth

I'm completely new to this area, but what I want to do is to start a process which listens for anyone trying to authenticate with my client credentials. I can't seem to find any good infromations about this matter so i would appriciate any help i can get.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Explain your usage of the Google auth scenario. for example, monitoring your client website traffic behaviour is possible in auth2.0 .
**According to Google Documentation** 
 " You can use information returned by the client object to help sync your site's user experience across multiple tabs and devices for your user." ... words from the google developer documentation "https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/session-state" ..

Comment: What I'm doing is to send links to users email, asking them to access their google calendar. And i need to continuously wait for many user to authenticate, and as i described in my post is the only way i could think of doing it